# Adjust a Material Icon's Width

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I use Angular with Angular Material and have a md-button with an icon and a text. You can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/opn0zge9

Code:

```
<md-button layout="row" style="width:80px;" layout-align="center center" ng-href="">
  <div class="material-icons" style="font-size: 36px;">keyboard_arrow_left</div>
  <div translate>Back</div>
</md-button>
```

The icon has a width of 36px. I want it to be smaller, e.g. 24 px. Setting the width of element `<div class="material-icons">` does not help since there's still the same large padding left of the icon.

How can I give the icon a width of 24px and achieve that it is centered within these 24px?

Comment: the icon has font-size of 36px not width. What do you exactly want?

Comment: yeah you can set font-size to 24px to get a width of 24px, but then you've set md-button padding to 13px or something as per your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the icon is controlled by your `font-size` of that icon.
If you want to move it to the right you can add negative `margin`.

```
.material-icons {
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can add a negative margin, see http://jsfiddle.net/opn0zge9/2/ The problem is, that the icon + text is not centered in the button.